# Having difficulty with my plots colors and creating a legend

Tags: r, colors, plot, legend

This is probably a basic question. I’ve produced a plot that displays the home ranges for different lemurs. Great! Hard part done. But they are all lime green. How can I choose a different colour for each of my 5 ID's? It seems like is should be simple but I can’t see anything online. Would anyone be able to suggest something?

I’ve pasted my code below

```
dd <- read.csv(file.choose(), header = T)
xy <- dd[,c("X","Y")]
id <- dd[,"ID"]
hr<- mcp(xy,id,percent=95)
plot(hr,
main="95% Minimum Convex Polygon",
xlab="X Coordinate",
ylab="Y Coordinate")
```

Once i have 5 separate colors for my 5 ID's (frodo, bilbo, merry, pippin, sam) it would also be great to create a legend displaying the colors and the related ID.  I was playing around with the following code

```
legend('topright', names(hr)[-1] , 
lty=1, col=c('red', 'blue', 'green',' brown'), bty='o', cex=1.5)
```

But that seems to just display a legend for the x,y coordinates not my ID's displayed in the plot.  Can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Edit: I got it! The function "col=" doesnt work for polygons. Its "colpol=" Thanks for all the help

Comment: could you `dput` your dataframe `dd` so we can replicate the data. We can't read you're csv file

Comment: Also what is `mcp` - is it from the `multcomp` package?

Comment: I would guess it s rather from package `adehabitatHR` given the context.

Comment: Have you checked out `ggplot2`?  It's good for creating lots of types of pretty plots.  Here is an example: http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_point.html

Comment: Its the adehabitat package, I know I should probably be using adehabitatHR as its the more updated version but I cant get it to work.  the MCP fuction create minimum convex polygons, essentially home ranges.  The percentage 95% eliminates the outliers

Comment: Also I'm not quite sure how to dput a file.  I assume that's like uploading it here?

Comment: @Colin just run `dput(hr)` and copy and paste into your question

Answer (score 1):

The hr object has a class of "area" and "data.frame". There is an area method for `plot`. It has a colpol argument. See `?plot.area` when adehabitat is loaded:

```
 plot(hr, colpol=c('red', 'blue', 'green',' brown') )
```

Originally it was not clear that you wanted to color the 4 (not 5) areas produced. I thought you wanted the points colored by group, which is what this produced. 
If you know that ID is already a factor then the factor call is not needed. `as.numeric` applied to a factor turns it into an integer ranging from 1 to the number of levels, and that is being used as an index into that vector of 5 colors. If you want to see the names all of the 657 colors available, just type `colors()`. Refer to `?colors` for additional links for managing color palettes.
As pointed out, we don't have the data or the `mcp` function to see what the hr object gets plotted as. If the plot method for that object is not assigning individual colors for the points, then do this instead:

```
 points(xy[,1], xy[,2],
 col = c("red", "green", "blue", "orange", "sandybrown")[as.numeric(factor(dd[,"ID"]))]
)
```

Comment: I tried to the top one you suggested and got the message:

Error in plot.area(hr, main = "95% Minimum Convex Polygon", xlab = "X Coordinate",  : argument 5 matches multiple formal arguments

The second one you suggested does plot all my points with different colors for each ID, but doesnt use the mcp or pecentage function.

Comment: So the unstated package that has `mcp` has a plot method for the objects created. You asked for colored points and you can use the `points` function to lay them on top of the plot produced by `plot.mcp`. Or you can add a `library()` call for the package so we can know what animal you are dealing with.

Comment: Its the adehabitat package.  Sorry I wasnt clear about that.  I honestly thought this would be simple query and the package wouldn't affect it.  Obviously it is affecting it.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for

```
plot(hr$X,hr$Y,main="95% Minimum Convex Polygon",xlab="X Coordinate",
 ylab="Y Coordinate",
 col = rainbow(length(hr$ID))[rank(hr$ID)],
 pch=c(1:25)[as.numeric(factor(hr$ID))])

 legend('topleft', unique(unlist(as.character(factor(hr$ID)))) ,lty=1, 
   col=rainbow(length(hr$ID))[ unique(unlist(rank(hr$ID)))],
   pch=c(1:25)[unique(unlist(as.numeric(factor(hr$ID))))], 
   bty='o', cex=1.5)
```

Comment: No Im sorry it isn't.  The MCP function creates a polygon The "hr$X,hr$Y" you've suggested seems to plot points, whilst good, it isn't what I need to produce.  I honestly don't understand though Why adding "col=....etc" to my script that worked perfectly makes it break down.  Its like the colour cannot be amended and im stuck with several unidentifiable lime green polygons

Comment: I dont think im explaining myself well so I made [this pic](http://imgur.com/cTN8oQ1).  The top graph is what it looks like as standard.  All lime.  The bottom is your adjustments but they arent really polygon, just plotted points

Comment: I figured it out! It was something silly.  The function "col=" doesnt work for polygons.  Its "colpol="  Thats it.  Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @Colin well done! might be a good idea to put the answer up somewhere for other people to see.